# How to get member type of boost::mpl placeholders during fold

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, boost-mpl, boost-fusion

Say there are two classes:

```
struct A
{
    using Key = int;
    using Value = char;
};

struct B
{
    using Key = char;
    using Value = float;
};
```

I want to use their member types to define the Fusion map:

```
typedef boost::fusion::map
<
    boost::fusion::pair< int , char > ,
    boost::fusion::pair< char , float >
> desired_type;
```

So I decided to use MPL fold to obtain the type:

```
typedef boost::fusion::result_of::as_map< boost::mpl::fold
<
    boost::mpl::vector< A , B > ,

    boost::fusion::map< > ,

    boost::fusion::result_of::push_back
    <
        boost::mpl::_1 ,
        boost::fusion::result_of::make_pair
        <
            boost::mpl::_2 ::Key , boost::mpl::_2 ::Value
        >
    >
>::type >::type map_type;
```

But of course that couldn't work, as `boost::mpl::_N` are really metafunctions returning the Nth argument.

So, I defined two auxiliary metafunctions:

```
template< class T >
struct GetInnerKey
{
    typedef typename T::Key type;
};

template< class T >
struct GetInnerValue
{
    typedef typename T::Value type;
};
```

and defined the fold properly:

```
typedef boost::fusion::result_of::as_map< boost::mpl::fold
<
    boost::mpl::vector< A , B > ,

    boost::fusion::map< > ,

    boost::fusion::result_of::push_back
    <
        boost::mpl::_1 ,
        boost::fusion::result_of::make_pair
        <
            GetInnerKey< boost::mpl::_2 > , GetInnerValue< boost::mpl::_2 >
        >
    >
>::type >::type map_type;
```

([Live at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c915a2bc5b9a9138))

**My questions are:**

- Is there a way to get rid of `GetInnerKey< >` and `GetInnerValue< >` using something already defined in MPL or Fusion?
- Is there a way to avoid using `boost::fusion::result_of::as_map< >`?
- Is this the right approach to accomplish my intent?

Answer (score 1):

Place holders are meta-functions and should be used with lazy evaluation. The **::type**s inside placeholders _1 & _2 are some complex types before evaluation (You could check them by **typeof** (with g++)).

As class A & B are not meta functions, so probably you have to write meta functions to handle interactions with class A & B.

e.g.

```
template <class PT1, class... PTs>
struct map_type
{
    typedef typename map_type<PTs...>::type pts_map;
    typedef typename boost::fusion::result_of::as_map<
        boost::fusion::joint_view<
            boost::fusion::map<
                boost::fusion::pair< typename PT1::Key, typename PT1::Value>
            >,
            pts_map
        >
    >::type type;
};

template <class PT1>
struct map_type<PT1>
{
    typedef boost::fusion::map<
        boost::fusion::pair< typename PT1::Key, typename PT1::Value>
    > type;
};
```

[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b939ac6746350b8b)